# Casting python list to numpy array gives the wrong shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am reading data from a file, like so:

```
f = open('some/file/path')
data = f.read().split('\n')
```

Which gives me something like `data = ['1 a #', '3 e &']`
if the original file was

> 1 a #
>
> 3 e &

I need it in a form like

`[['1','a','#'],['3','e','&']]`

so that I can then do a `np.swapaxes()` on it and turn it into

`[['1','3'],['a','e'],['#','&']]`

But whenever I do do that, the `swapaxes` call fails, and it is because I am not ending up with a numpy array of the right shape. To turn the strings into lists of strings, I do:

```
for n in range(len(data)): data[n] = data[n].split()
data = np.array(data)
```

But when i check the shape:

```
np.shape(data)
>>>(2,)
```

So I cannot swap axes. I've tried doing the `numpy` array in a few different ways but everything seems to create a `numpy` array that doesn't know there is another dimension inside of the arrays within the array.

Comment: Take another look at the contents of `data`. Are you sure it matches what you think it should be? It sounds to me like your file probably ends in a `'\n'`, treating the character as a line *terminator* rather than a line *separator*.

Answer (score 0):

To turn `data = ['1 a #', '3 e &']` into `[['1','a','#'],['3','e','&']]` you should do:

```
>>> data2 = []
>>> for line in data:
    data2.append(line.split())


>>> data2
[['1', 'a', '#'], ['3', 'e', '&']]
```

Comment: This does not work. I still end up with what numpy thinks is an array with one axis.

Comment: Well I showed you how to convert it into a list you requested, no experience with numpy unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

split the strings first:

```
import numpy as np
data = ['1 a #', '3 e &']
np.array([x.split() for x in data]).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line split looks fine

```
In [110]: data = ['1 a #', '3 e &']

In [111]: for n in range(len(data)): data[n] = data[n].split()

In [112]: data
Out[112]: [['1', 'a', '#'], ['3', 'e', '&']]

In [113]: A=np.array(data)

In [114]: A
Out[114]: 
array([['1', 'a', '#'],
       ['3', 'e', '&']], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [115]: A.shape
Out[115]: (2, 3)

In [116]: A.T
Out[116]: 
array([['1', '3'],
       ['a', 'e'],
       ['#', '&']], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [117]: A.T.tolist()
Out[117]: [['1', '3'], ['a', 'e'], ['#', '&']]
```

I can 'transpose' a list of lists with `zip` as well:

```
In [119]: list(zip(*data))
Out[119]: [('1', '3'), ('a', 'e'), ('#', '&')]
```

The original list spliting can also be done with a list comprehension

```
In [120]: [i.split() for i in ['1 a #', '3 e &']]
Out[120]: [['1', 'a', '#'], ['3', 'e', '&']]
```

You could have combined the file read and splits with something like

```
[i.strip().split() for i in f.readlines()]
```

`readlines` returns a list of lines, but they still include the `\n`, which `strip` removes.  The other thing to watch out for is blank lines between the data lines

===================

In case it wasn't clear,

```
In [122]: data = ['1 a #', '3 e &']

In [123]: np.array(data)
Out[123]: 
array(['1 a #', '3 e &'], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

produces a 2 element array, where each element is a 5 character string.  No amount of reshaping or transposing will convert this into an array of single element strings.  You can reshape it into other 2 element arrays

```
In [124]: _.reshape(2,1)
Out[124]: 
array([['1 a #'],
       ['3 e &']], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [125]: __.reshape(1,2,1)
Out[125]: 
array([[['1 a #'],
        ['3 e &']]], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

I could `view` it as a single character array:

```
In [128]: A.view('<U1')
Out[128]: 
array(['1', ' ', 'a', ' ', '#', '3', ' ', 'e', ' ', '&'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [129]: A.view('<U1').reshape(5,2)
Out[129]: 
array([['1', ' '],
       ['a', ' '],
       ['#', '3'],
       [' ', 'e'],
       [' ', '&']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

but those blank characters get in the way.

There is also a library that applies string functions to arrays:

```
np.concatenate(np.char.split(A)).reshape(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file(strip() will remove the '\n'):

`filename="some/file/path"
data=[i.strip().split(' ') for i in open(filename)]
print(data)`

Converting list to numpy array and swap the axis:

`import numpy as np
print(np.asarray(data))
print(np.asarray(data).T)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. `np.shape(data)` gives me `(2244,)`, and swapping the axes does nothing

Comment: I think there might be some special things in your file. I try with my python3, it works well. If you try np.shape(data) and it gives you (2244,), I think you had better check your reading file step because it seems that the data are not properly read. Could you print some information about your input file? In addition, I also try np.swapaxes(data,0,1), and it also works.